# Using $_SESSION to route users

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm building an application that has a user log in to access the controls. Based on where that user is located, (in one of three places), I need to have different sets of information called up from a database based on where they are. Should/could I use the php sessions functionality to grab a piece of data from the login form that defines where the user is located, and pass that among all the pages I need it on without it getting lost?

Comment: something like `$_SESSION['YOURNAME'] = $_POST['YOURFORMINPUTNAME']` after a user hits log-in page where you analyze `$_POST` data to log him/her in.

Answer (score 1):

That's certainly a valid way to handle it.  On the page processing the form:

```
<?php
   if ($_POST['formlocation'] === 'location1') {
      $_SESSION['location'] = 'location1';
   }
   if ($_SESSION['location']
?>
```

And then on the control panel page:

```
<?php
   if ($_SESSION['location'] === 'location1') {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE location='".$_SESSION['location']."'";
     .
     .
     .
   }
?>
```

Just as a side note, if by location you mean 'which page they are on' you should use a hidden form input named 'formlocation' (just as an example obviously) inside the form so it is automatically submitted with its value attribute passed along.

Answer (score 0):

In short - no.  What does "located" mean - is that geography, IP subnet, etc?  We need more info, but in general you shouldn't presume the IP address will provide any locational help as it can be spoofed through a proxy and about a half dozen other ways.

More info needed for additional help, please elaborate.

Comment: Clearly he means where they are located on the site or based off of a specific form input with only three options.  Clearly he did not mean their geographical location based upon IP, given that he said 'in one of three locations'

Comment: well i thought he meant geographically to, so not so 'clear' to all.

Comment: Sorry for issues with clarity.  user2024011 is right, thats the general idea i'm working with.